# Assigning a Google Tag Manager (GTM) account to Google Analytics account

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a client who has a Google Analytics (GA) account (analytics@client.com). We have have access to the GA account (analytics@client.com).

If I visit the Google Tag Manager (GTM) still signed into Google Chrome as the GA account email (analytics@client.com), there is no account associated in GTM.

The client however does have a GTM account, however it has been set up by an employee of the client (employee@client.com). When I access their Google Chrome and visit GTM (signed in as employee@client.com), I can see two accounts set up here.

Inside one of them is a group of triggers that have been set up. In the other account within GTM when signed in as the employee it has no triggers.

I suspect the wrong account is currently pointed to the GA account (analytics@client.com).

The GTM account set up by employee@client.com with the triggers, I would like to apply to GA (analytics@client.com).

Is there a kind soul out there who is able to help guide me to achieve the desired result?

**How can I assign a GTM account under one email address (employee@client.com) to show and track the analytics of their triggers, while viewing the Google Analytics registered under a second email address (analytics@client.com)?**